# Can not reference (subclassed) Swift classes after set failed: failed after changed to BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION = YES

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks, xcframework

The problem is as the title.

Here is the reproduce steps:

1. Create a project based on Objective-C
2. Create a Swift class which subclass UIViewController. It will create a bridging header automatically.
3. Use the Swift class within the Objective-C project (e.g. the default ViewController) by adding "#import "FooProjectName-Swift.h" to the top of the Objective-C file.
4. set BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION = YES (The WWDC video talked about [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/416/))
5. Xcode will show an error that suggests us to remove the briding header
6. Remove the briding header as suggested
7. The Swift class will not be referenced, and Xcode shows the error

Here is the sample project with commits showing these steps
https://github.com/allenlinli/BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION-Bug-When-Use-Swift

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: It's:
"Unknown type name 'TheViewController'"
And
"Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type"

Comment: That's got nothing to do with `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION`; you have syntax errors.  `ViewController.m` line 13 references a type `TheViewController` which does not exist.  It's not clear to me what the correct declaration is here though.

Comment: The `TheViewController` is declared in the file File.swift, you can find it by searching the keyword `TheViewController`.

Comment: You'll need the bridging header.  I don't know why it was suggested you remove it, but I don't see how Objective-C can see the declaration of the type without it.

Comment: The earlier commit (with sha 93bd33c) had the bridging header, but Xcode showed the error:
`<unknown>:0: error: using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported`

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that I should set only `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION = YES` for a framework target, not a sample app target.